# Проблемы с "github.com/andelf/go-curl/curl" Centos 5 x64

Tags: golang, curl, centos

Добрый день.
Накропал для друга небольшую программку на Go. Пограмма использует пакет "[github.com/andelf/go-curl/curl](https://github.com/andelf/go-curl)" У меня на домашнем ноубуке ArchLinux x64 все прекрасно.
Но при попытке эту же программу запустить на его сервере Centos5 x64 ругается на отсутствие библиотеки libcurl.so.4

```
[user@host ~]$ ./programm
./programm: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

При этом curl у него установлен. Если верить yum последняя версия

```
[root@host ~]# yum install curl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.softaculous.com
 * epel: fedora.kiewel-online.ch
 * extras: mirror.softaculous.com
 * rpmforge: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * updates: mirror.softaculous.com
Reducing CentOS-5 Testing to included packages only
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Package curl-7.15.5-15.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package curl-7.15.5-15.el5.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Попытался прямо у него установить Go и запустить программу из исходников, результат так-же неутешительный

```
[user@host ~]$ go run  ./programm-SRC/main.go
# github.com/andelf/go-curl/curl
error: 'curl_easy_recv' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
error: 'curl_easy_pause' undeclared (first use in this function)
error: 'curl_easy_send' undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А libcurl.so.4 там есть? А то, может в последнем-то пакете какая-нибудь другая версия.

Comment: В том то и дело что нет. У него есть libcurl.so и libcurl.so.3 а libcurl.so.4 нет вовсе и откуда его установить непонятно. Вчера уже, когда все идеи закончились, от безнадеги отправил ему свой файл libcurl.so.4 в надежде что может подцепит, но этот фокус не удался...

Comment: Найти, в каком пакете есть эта библиотека. У меня, в ubuntu 10.04 она в пакете libcurl3. Точнее, там libcurl.so.4.1.1, а libcurl.so.4 -- симлинк на неё.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обычная проблема линковки и версионности. Тут только:

- собирать статично
- собирать для каждого дистрибутива
- распространять сразу с либами и запускать с измененной переменное окружения  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- собирать прямо на машине пользователя.
- можно рискнуть и сделать симлинк, но никто ничего не гарантирует ;Ъ

*P.S. "Собирать" нужно читать как "линковать"*

Comment: Симлинк libcurl.so.4 на libcurl.so.3.x.y? Месье понимает толк в извращениях.

Comment: Ну я предупредил, если что :D. Может работать, а может и не работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum install curl-devel
```

не?

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению не:( Он уже установлен.